# How can I get the URL of an image uploaded to Firebase and add it to a MongoDB object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on a blog where the user comes up with a title and writes some content to create a blog post. There's also an option to include an image for your post.

```
    <Form.Group className="my-2" controlId="content">
      <label>Image</label>
      <input
        type="file"
        placeholder="Image"
        onChange={handleImageChange}
      ></input>
    </Form.Group>
```

The image is stored inside Firebase. Both publishing an article and uploading the image is working at intended.

```
  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const username = userInfo.name;

    const imageName = image.name;
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${imageName}`);

    uploadBytes(imageRef, image).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
        setImageUrl(url);
      });
    });

    try {
      const res = await write({
        title,
        content,
        username,
        placement,
        image: imageUrl,
      }).unwrap();
      navigate("/");
      toast.success("Article Added!");
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(err?.data?.message || err.error);
    }
  };
```

The `handleImage` just selects the first image that you select and uploads it.

The `submitHandler` does the bulk of the code.

It first uploads the image and then generates the URL. The `setImageUrl` gets the URL and adds it to `state` and right below it adds the URL to the `image` path of the blog. Inside the SingleBlog Component I'm mapping the data out, including the image.

```
<div>
  <h1 className={styles.title}>{blog.title}</h1>
  <p>by {blog.author}</p>
  <img src={blog.image} alt="" fill className={styles.image} />
  <p>{blog.content}</p>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having (I think) is the URL is being generated **after** the blog post is created, so often times the object is left with an empty string for the image path. If I include `required: true` inside the article schema, it sometimes is quick enough to generate the URL and include it in the path.

I'm wondering what the best solution to my problem is. What I'm trying to do is create a blog with the title, content and image path and upload it all at once and save it inside my MongoDB so that I can map the data and show the image on screen with an `img` tag.

Comment: Either `await` for the image upload to complete, get the image URL, and then create the article. Or, create the article first, and then upload the image and update the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `then` on a promise does not block the progress of that code like `await` does.  It just sets up a callback to be invoked later when the promise resolves.  You should use await on the promises returned by Firebase Storage to make the code execute in sequence (and also make it a whole lot easier to read).

```
const snapshot = await uploadBytes(imageRef, image);
const url = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
setImageUrl(url);
```